# How many pairs $(p, m)$ exist, where $p$ is a prime and $m$ is an integer, such that $\frac{m^3-pm+1}{m^2+pm+2}$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many pairs $(p, m)$ exist, where $p$ is a prime and $m$ is an integer, such that $$\frac{m^3-pm+1}{m^2+pm+2}$$ is an integer? I've found three pairs by myself, but I'm not sure if that's all. What's the good algorithm for solving this type of problems?

Comment: Well, if $p$ is odd then the numerator is odd for all $m$ but the denominator is even, so you must have $p=2$.

Comment: does one allow $p=-2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on lulu's comment: once you know that $p=2$, you can simplify the expression.

$$\frac{m^3-2m+1}{m^2+2m+2} = m+ \frac{-2m^2-4m+1}{m^2+2m+2} = m-2+ \frac{5}{m^2+2m+2}$$

So $m^2+2m+2$ is $1,5, -1$ or $-5$. 
You can solve these four quadratic equations to obtain all solutions. (Or alternatively, you can observe that $m^2+2m+2=(m+1)^2+1$, so $m$ is between $-3$ and $1$, and check all five possibilities.)

It is also unclear to me if $p=-2$ should be allowed or not. In that case, a similar calculation works, too.